# connect and get data from MS CRM online using a service bus

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I am having a windows azure site and i want to connect to CRM online, i found that the only way to do this in azure is to connect and configure a service bus with CRM online.

I setup and configure the service bus to work with my CRM instance and also to receive messages based on certain activity as CRM SDK contains samples for that.

My issue is how to load leads data and send it as a message and then process the response message in the listener to bind it in my azure web app.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried here yet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309677.aspx